# R error "no observations remain after removing missing values" for function aov_car

Tags: r, anova

Problem: I am trying to run a mixed ANOVA in R.  When I run the ANOVA, I get an error saying that all of my data values are missing.

This is what the data look like (just the first few rows):
[Screenshot of data after running View(SWL_data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzN3k.png)

When I try to run the ANOVA, I get an error that all the cases are missing values even though they clearly have values when I look at the data file in View(). [ANOVA code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAlzQ.png)

I checked each of the object types.  [R code and output of object types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcM6o.png)

I am not sure how to share the code so that this problem is reproducible without sharing all of my data. This is my first post so thank you for your patience with me!

Comment: Please share your code and error as plain text and never as images. THank you.

Comment: use `dput(x)` to provide your data

Comment: You seem to have only one observation per participant (`str()` output shows 172 rows of data and 172 different values for `participant`). Therefore, it seems odd to me that you try to run a mixed ANOVA with participant-specific error terms. I guess there is either a statistical misconception or part of the data missing. If the question is about statistics, better take it over to CrossValidated to get a good answer.